# Apache 2 on ubuntu segfault

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Apache is segfaulting on only one of my sites (which works fine on another dev machine) It will load fine for the first few requests after i restart apache but then it will just segfault until i restart it again

Comment: ^ In other words..we need more information.  I have Apache running multiple sites on Ubuntu, and none of them segfault.

Comment: Maybe Nginx will work.

Comment: Or you could try running Apache on CentOS

Comment: Do you have anything in /var/log/messages that reference apachectl?? Add all these details to your post above using the edit button.

Comment: im on ubuntu 12.04. I dont see anything in messages. I cant even seem to find a pattern in the faults, it happened when i stepped down my primary database to switch the secondary at the new host to a primary

Comment: You're going to have a log or core dump. That will have your answer.

Comment: Please update your question to include any and all pertinent details for troubleshooting.  Many people here are willing to help if you give them enough information, but as it currently stands, your question is way too vague (and also off-topic for Stack Overflow; try again on http://serverfault.com/ if you manage to articulate a question with enough details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a lot more detail in your post. However to figure out a segfault you should install gdb using the following command. You may have to use a backport.

```
xxx$ echo "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
xxx$ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install gdb
```

Then

```
xxx$ sudo apt-get install apache2-dbg php5-dbg
```

Then

```
xxx$ CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache-coredumps
```

You may have to increase the core file size by default using the commands below

```
xxx$ ulimit -c unlimited
xxx$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
```

Then restart Apache and wait for the next segfault. Once that has occured you want to use gdb to read in the core file

```
xxx$ gdb apache2 -core /tmp/apache-coredumps/core
```

I hope this helps. It is somewhat high level considering your post though.